# Why Redux Strore does not add new entry

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/alexnm/react-ssr). I have trouble adding one more entry to the Redux store. 
Modified this [file](https://github.com/alexnm/react-ssr/blob/master/src/store.js) like this:

```
const storeNavItemsData = ( data ) => ( {
type: "STORE_NAV_ITEMS",
data,
 } );

.......

export function fetchNavItemsData() { 
return function(dispatch){
   return fetchFromExternal( ).then( res => dispatch(storeNavItemsData(res)) );
   }
 }
```

Added new function to call external system in this [file](https://github.com/alexnm/react-ssr/blob/master/src/api.js)

```
   export function fetchFromExternal( ) {
return fetch( "http:/result.json" )
    .then( res => res.json( ) )
    .then( res => res.items );
  }
```

I have modified [this](https://github.com/alexnm/react-ssr/blob/master/src/components/Home.js) file like this

```
import { fetchData, fetchNavItemsData} from "../store";
.....
Home.serverNavFetch = fetchNavItemsData;
..... 
const mapDispatchToProps = {
fetchData,
fetchNavItemsData,
};
```

Now modified this [file](https://github.com/alexnm/react-ssr/blob/master/src/server.js)

```
  const dataRequirements =
    routes
        .filter( route => matchPath( req.url, route ) ) 
        .map( route => route.component ) 
        .filter( comp => comp.serverFetch )
        .map( comp => store.dispatch( comp.serverFetch( ) ) )
        .filter( comp1 => comp1.serverNavFetch )
        .map( comp1 => store.dispatch( comp1.serverNavFetch( ) ) );
```

After I do not see Redux store is populated as expected, values are blank.

```
            window.REDUX_DATA = {"loggedIn":true,"data":[],"navItems":[]}
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The redux dev tools can provide valuable information such as: is the action dispatched and did the action cause state changes.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code in the repo try adding a new reducer to add new store entity  -

```
const reducer = combineReducers( {
    loggedIn: sessionReducer,
    data: dataReducer,
    navData : navReducer // new reducer added here
} );

navReducer.js // this is the reducer file
const dataReducer = ( state = [ ], action ) => {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case "STORE_NAV_ITEMS":
            return action.data;
        default: return state;
    }
};
```

to access the value stored in the redux store, map the store to component file-

```
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => ( {
navData: state.navData,
});
```

Now after this you can access the value as props - `this.props.navData`